# When posting, are tag counts a good indicator of where to post?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a question I'd like to ask and am debating whether to post on StackOverflow or ServerFault.

The question is regarding the programmatic deployment process of a web site to IIS using msdeploy.

It's both a development-related question and a server-related question in my opinion. Technically, the subject-matter could tip it towards ServerFault I think.

However, SO has 21.k items tagged as `iis` and 811 tagged as `msdeploy` vs. ServerFault's 3.8k and 42 respectively.

Are the tag counts a good indicator in this case of where I should post the question? It would seem to me that this is where the expertise can be found.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the expertise is. You should post where your question is on topic. And if you look at pure numbers, the fact that SO has WAY more questions than any other site in the network should be a factor, no?

Comment: Assuming it is actually on-topic on both sites, any site with tag count > 50 is probably a good place to post it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu - "Million lemmings **can be mistaken**"!!!

Comment: @LazyBadger and surely at least one of the million lemmings will be able to answer.

Answer (score 3):

Tag counts are an indicator, not the indicator.

What is on-topic and what not is on a high-level described in the Help Center. Based on that contour the community further details that either on meta or by voting on the main site.

If you conclude that your question could be on-topic on several sites, you can use tags to further determine if your question would fit. Don't use tag counts for that but visit the tag wiki and see if they have guidance on the kind of questions that should be tagged with that specific tag on that site.

Also visit the questions asked in that tag to learn which questions go well and which ones struggle. Compare in which category your question will end up. Alternatively you might ask in a site specific chat room.

If that research isn't conclusive you could post on meta and share the question you want to ask and the inconclusive results of all your research. This will be beneficial for the community because they can improve the tag-wiki's and you get a tailor made advice without the risk of getting your question down voted because of a subtle difference in on-topic-ness you didn't notice.